CMDIChildWndex is undefined for SOME .cpp files in my MFC project
I have a C++ MFC dialog app that has been compiling properly. I have made several changes and It is now getting errors that CMDIChildWndEx is undefined. I know that it is included by afxmdiclientarea.h.  I am not using MDI or child windows and have not changed the system include files I am using, the order in which they are included or which ones are included in the source files. There are three source files:

the main dialog file containing the code for creating the dialog window and handling all Windows messages and members to populate the text-controls and get setup information for the user.
The thread that does the work required by the inputs from the user.
The code that initializes all global variables used by the members in the first 2 files (using data supplied
The only window is created by the main dialog, which does NOT have a menu or taskbar. The only other “windows” are from calls to MessageBox. The code in file 2 does not get these errors and has the same includes as the other 2 files.
What mystifies me is that the program builds and runs properly, in spite of these errors.

Why am I getting these syntax errors and how can I correct them?
I made sure the other files did the same includes in the same order. In spite of the problems, the build completes OK and the program does what it is supposed to do.
Note: my code does NOT try to include this file, it is being automatically included by atlmfc

The short answer is that an older version of the program specified the C++17 language standard but the current version with the new errors, specified the C++20 standard. Reverting my project settings to the older standard made the #include errors disappear. (aside:) I don't understand why reverting the spec should make a difference. My understanding of the "rules" for the standards is that old "correctly written" programs must still compile correctly (recall that my new version DID build successfully, even with the "errors" the compiler "found"!!).
